# Unable to move between textboxes using the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble with my javascript and was hoping you could help.

I'm using an example from here: http://www.knowlbase.in/2012/01/traverse-cursor-through-text-box-with.html to move between textboxes on a page. Left and Right works great but up and down moves the cursor diagonally to right (it does however move diagonally up when the up key is pressed and diagonally down when the down key is pressed).

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Edit- adding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYU76/)

This is what I've got:

```
function arrowKeyPressed() {
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 39)
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
    else if (e.which == 37)
        $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus();
    else if (e.which == 40)
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();
    else if (e.which == 38)
        $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();
});
};
```

and this is how I add my textbox attribute (all the textboxes are created programitically):

```
tb.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "arrowKeyPressed()");
```

Here's what the HTML looks like when generated(this is only one textbox; all of the others are identical, with the exception of the tab index):

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$addPrices$Textbox101"
type="text"id="ctl00_MainContent_addPrices_Textbox101" tabindex="13" 
onblur="validateText('ctl00_MainContent_addPrices_Textbox101', 
'ctl00_MainContent_addPrices_AddQuote', 'ctl00_MainContent_addPrices_msgLbl')" 
style="width:60px;">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the html look like? Can you add an example on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Just one input element isn't enough here. Could you setup a small example (a table with 2-3 rows and 2-3 cols which looks like the one you are actually using) on jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry Andreas, jsfiddle now added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invalid HTML is the problem here. `<th />` are only allowed in an `<thead />` element.
So if you replace the `<th />` tags for the first column with `<td />` it works fine.

```
<tr>
    <td>2013 04 Apr</td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:60px;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:60px;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:60px;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:60px;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:60px;">
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!-- ... -->
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arJZc/1/)

**Edit**
The reason for the "wrong" behaviour is the `<th />` but for completeness I will elaborate the **why** a little bit more.

```
$(this).closest('td').index()
```

This determines the index of the `<td />` in the row (including the `<th />`).
This index you're using for building a selector which looks only for `<td />` elements.

```
'td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')'
```

So you are "missing" the first column (`<th />`).

Comment: You Sir, are a star. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery`. I mean, use this function in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 39)
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
        else if (e.which == 37)
            $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').focus();
        else if (e.which == 40)
            $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();
        else if (e.which == 38)
            $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq(' + $(this).closest('td').index() + ')').find('input').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried using this but it never seems to get fired until I add a 'onkeyup' event onto the textbox.